# Gitlab yml include external yml files

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I am trying to add my stages to sub yamls, and i need to share them with other repos so i want them to be in a shared repo

I have this working with include and local in the .gitlab-ci.yml
but when I moved the .yml to a different repo to be shard with the others I get
Included file `.gitlab-ci.yml` does not have valid YAML syntax!
or
Included file `https://git.com/group/folder/pipeline/-/raw/main/.static-analysis.yml` does not have valid YAML syntax!

I have tried the below to solve the issue.

```
image: python:3.9

stages:
  - static-analysis

include: 
  - project: 'group/folder/templates/pipeline/'
      ref: main
      file: '.static-analysis.yml'
```

Included file `.gitlab-ci.yml` does not have valid YAML syntax!

```
image: python:3.9

stages:
  - static-analysis

include: 
  - remote: 'https://git.com/group/folder/pipeline/-/raw/main/.static-analysis.yml'
```

Included file `https://git.com/group/folder/pipeline/-/raw/main/.static-analysis.yml` does not have valid YAML syntax!

I have got this to work with the following, but this will not share with the other repos

```
image: python:3.9

stages:
  - static-analysis

include: 
  - local: '.static-analysis.yml'
```

.static-analysis.yml

```
job:
  stage: static-analysis
  script:
    - echo "test"
```

Answer (score 1):

> Included file https://git.com/group/folder/pipeline/-/raw/main/.static-analysis.yml does not have valid YAML syntax!

This is most likely because your project does not have public visibility. You can only include files using `remote:` that don't require any authentication to access.

If your shared project is in the same gitlab instance, the correct method is to use `include: project:`

```yaml
include:
  project: mygroup/myproject
  file: 
    - path/to/gitlab-ci.yml
    - path/to/another/ci.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

found my bug there where spaces before ref and file. but still cant use remote

```yaml
image: python:3.9

stages:
  - static-analysis
  - build

include: 
  - project: 'group/folder/templates/pipeline/'
    ref: main
    file: '.static-analysis.yml' 
  - project: 'group/folder/templates/pipeline/'
    ref: main
    file: '.build.yml'
```